# XFA PDF Fill data into duplicate field ID

Tags: pdf, npm, jspdf, pdf.js

Using the library pdf.js

IRCC XFA Ref: https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5257b_1.pdf

In this XFA form, the fieldid and dataid values are duplicates for multiple controls. E.g. `familyname`

For example:

```
{ 
        "name": "textarea", 
        "attributes": { 
            "dataId": "field284442", 
            "fieldId": "field284442", 
            "class": [ 
                "xfaTextfield" 
            ], 
            "aria-label": "Question 1 Family name as shown on your passport or travel document", 
            "aria-required": true, 
            "required": true, 
            "tabindex": 5002, 
            "maxLength": 100 
        } 
    } 
}
```

https://prnt.sc/Mxel9q-YRrUE

https://prnt.sc/KQse9WsR_3Y8

Issue: If I want to update the `field284442` with value `{john}`, the code does not work due to duplicate id.

`pdf.annotationStorage.setValue('field284442', { value: 'John' });`

Could you help me with:

1. If there is we can avoid the duplicates; and update the text control to set value?
2. is there any way so that we can traverse to that particular child node and set value?

Any sample code, link to a solution or inputs are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.